# SyntaxError: JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, json

SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 3 column 5 of the JSON data

получаю такую ошибку в этой функции. 
вот на эту строку var data = JSON.parse($("#dcsel").text());

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fetch-dc-block').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url : defaultPath + 'reports/getRCJson',
            cache : false,
            processData : false,
            type : 'GET',
            processData : false,
            contentType : "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
            success : function(response) {
                if (typeof response == "object") {
                    $('#dcsel').val('');
                    var data = JSON.parse($("#dcsel").text());
                } else {
                    alert('Ошибка!');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

подскажите, что нужно исправить?
в json приходят данные в виде

```
Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>> map
```

HTML код элемента #dcsel

```
<div class="fetch-dc-block col-xs-4" align="right" id="ds">
            <%
                if ((entry != null) && (entry.get("use_dc") != null) && (entry.get("use_dc").length() > 0)) {
            %>
            <select size="5" multiple="multiple" title="РЦ" id="dcsel"
                name="dcenters" align="right">
                <%
```

...
%>

```
        <option <%if (sel) {%> selected <%}%> value="<%=dcEntry.get("id")%>"><%=dcEntry.get("name")%></option>
        <%
            }
        %>
    </select>
    <%
        }
    %>
</div>
```

код контроллера

```
    public void getRCJson(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
            DCManager dcm = new DCManager(pgCon); // запрос к БД
            Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("dc", dcm.getAllDC());
            pgCon.closeConnection();
            try {
                JSONResponse.sendJSONRequest(request, response, map);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Syslog.error(this, "Ошибка при отправке JSON ответа:" + e);
            }
        }
public static <T> void sendJSONRequest(final HttpServletRequest request,final HttpServletResponse response, T t) throws IOException {
        synchronized (response) {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            String dataJson = gson.toJson(t);
            PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
            try {
                synchronized (pw) {
                        pw.print(dataJson);
                        pw.close();
                }
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                Syslog.error(JSONResponse.class, "Ошибка при записи PrintWriter");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Покажите HTML код конкретно элемента `#dcsel`

Comment: добавил в вопрос

Comment: Зачем вы парсите содержимое дом-элемента, а не приходящий от сервера результат? Если вы хотите парсить полученный результат, то нужно использовать `var data = JSON.parse(response);`

Comment: вы данные покажите, а не то, что якобы приходит. Тем более что после возврата результата аякса, данные текста #dcsel не меняются

Comment: изменил, теперь ошибка SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Comment: Тогда давайте код на сервере теперь :)

Comment: добавил код с сервера

Comment: если сервер JsonResult возвращает, то parse делать и не надо

Comment: собтсвенно, его и не надо делать, ибо это и так не строка. вы же провели typeof = object

Comment: опаньки и точно))) вот жесть

Answer (score 1):

Данный метод разбирает JSON строку с последующим преобразованием в объект, у вас же приходит не JSON, соответственно она валится. Примеры корректных данных:

```
JSON.parse('{}');              // {}
JSON.parse('true');            // true
JSON.parse('"foo"');           // "foo"
JSON.parse('[1, 5, "false"]'); // [1, 5, "false"]
JSON.parse('null');            // null
JSON.parse('{"name":"Vasya", "surname": "Petrov"}'); 
/*{
     name: 'Vasya',
     surname: 'Petrov'
  }*/
```